# Непонятно условие цикла  --  while(1)

Tags: c++

Друзья, подскажите, в скобках условия цикла while -- единица. Это алгоритм "двоичный поиск". Алгоритм работает, но эта единица в условии цикла непонятна:

```
         while(1)
         {...........}
```

Comment: Вообще, это c-style, в c++ лучше писать `while(true)`

Comment: Кстати, можно зациклить не только традиционным while(true) или for(;;), но и с использованием операторов continue или goto, только там кода побольше будет.

Comment: Как это с goto кода больше ???

    L:;
    ....
    goto L;

Столько же букв, как и в while(1){ ... }, вот for(;;){ ... } на одну короче.

Comment: еще вариант - с помощью longjmp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это значит, что цикл бесконечный. Прервать его итерацию можно через break или return (ну или через throw).

Comment: Ты ещё goto не назвал.

Comment: goto --  не лучший способ. о нем и не знать не стыдно

Comment: не, о нем стыдно не знать. а использовать его еще стыднее.

Comment: >не, о нем стыдно не знать. а использовать его еще стыднее.

 Если его сделали, значит он нужен. Это инструмент, который нужно разумно использовать и не злоупотреблять им. Использовать или не использовать - решать программисту. Мне он пару раз пригождался, помогая *упростить* программу.

Comment: сделали его давно, и в некоторых древних языках (например, Basic, Fortran77) без него никак. Если пользовать, то крайне аккуратно и как можно меньше. И уж во всяком случае, не направо и налево.

Comment: Так в древних диалектах Basic вообще не было while (спасибо хоть for был), вот и приходилось goto обходиться. А в современных диалектах вполне можно и без goto жить.

Comment: Ну да, я в школе на Агатах на бейсике писал. одни сплошные goto

Comment: @mikillskegg А ещё есть злобный Столлман. (у него в gcc расширение языка есть -- переход по указателю)

Comment: Ну я тут в glibs несколько goto нашел.

Comment: А мой начальник умеет писать только на Fortran77. А там все циклы только с помощью goto реальзуются.

Comment: Усвоил одно - как веганы рассказывают, что "можно обходиться без мяса" (или чем его *заменить*), так и некоторые камрады рассказывают про goto :) А так да, злоупотреблять не надо)

Comment: @mikillskegg скажите начальнику, что там ещё циклы DO есть. Со времён fortran-II или раньше. А `goto` больше всего прикалывает в java

Comment: Хм, а кто-нибудь может толково рассказать, почему `goto` так плох? Вы так спорите, что выбирать программисту, а по сути решение принимается скорее всего методом "тыка", под сим методом понимаю, что логика программы упрощается, но проблема goto лежит несколько глубже, чем знания обычного программиста без бекграунда аппаратной части.

Comment: Главное, почему не рекомендуют использовать goto, это трудность чтения таких программ, трудность их поддержки и возможность появление труднообнаружимых ошибок.

Comment: @alexlz, в Джаве goto играет другую роль.

Comment: Structured Programming with go to Statements
DONALD E. KNUTH 

Кстати, **отличная статья** !!!

Comment: @avp больше на научный трактат похоже, лень сейчас читать.

Comment: Точно, в одной из аннотаций написано:

"To conclude: It's probably best not to read Knuth's paper in one sitting, for you almost surely will become mentally fatigued by the eight major examples, each of which is rewritten three or four (or more!) times in an ALGOL-like pseudocode. Read the paper piece by piece, and do read the code --- you'll learn a lot from it!"

Comment: Бессмертные труды древних?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, goto просто не соответствует методологии [структурного программирования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (также см. [Теорема Бёма-Якопини](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8))

Comment: Господа, про goto я не забыл, как было высказано в первых комментариях, просто лично сам не являюсь сторонником его использования. Полагаю, что при написании программ на прикладном, а не системном, уровне с использованием ООП, необходимость в использовании goto не возникает. 
В общем, о вкусах не спорят :)

Comment: Иногда (обычно когда нашли ошибку при проверке входных данных внутри вложенных условий в с циклами) очень удобно (и понятнее, чем флаги), но только вперед и на **одну и ту же** метку из разных мест.

Answer (score 6):

Общая форма цикла while имеет следующий вид:

```
while(условие) оператор; //(оператор это тело цикла)
```

Условие может быть любым допустимым выражение в языке. Функция проверяет на Истину или Ложь условие.

Если ИСТИНА то цикл продолжается (все что в теле цикла) - любое значение кроме 0.

Если ЛОЖЬ то цикл прекращается - 0.

В данном случае `while(1)`, `while(5)`, `while(-15)` истина - цикл продолжается бесконечно или пока в теле цикла не будет `break`, `exit()`, `return` или `goto`.

А `while(0)` уже ложь и цикл останавливается не начавшись.

Answer (score 3):

Ничего необычно - это просто значит исполнять этот цикл вечно. Классический способ.
Конечно, где то должен быть `break` или `return` что бы этот цикл остановить. Иначе он будет исполнятся очень долго:)

Answer (score 2):

Это цикл без условия. Он будет исполняться, пока ты не его не прервёшь при помощи операторов break, return, goto, вызова exit, ExitProcess или исключения. Также цикл без условия можно создать при помощи конструкции `for(;;) {...}`.

Comment: По-моему, `1` - очень даже условие, просто оно всегда истинно.

Comment: Это смотря, как понимать. Название сути не меняет.

 Я считаю, что условие - это какие-то ограничения. Всегда истинное условие не имеет смысла, потому что оно ничем не ограничивает код.

Comment: Предполагается что в скобках после while идет выражение (обычно булево, но возможно и арифметическое). 1 (которая true) тоже вполне себе выражение:) А насчет того, является ли 1 условием, над этим можно еще подумать. Или не подумать, а просто забить, потому что роли не играет.